# list files and folders in one hit using one drive

Tags: onedrive

I am currently integrating one drive with my application.
I am searching for an endpoint where i can get **all the files and folders of the user's one drive.**
I currently found an endpoint where I can use root/children to get the root files along with the nested folder count.

Is there any possible endpoint to get all files and folders ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discover all files and folders within a drive, your best bet is to use the [delta](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_delta) API. It'll end up returning all items, potentially over multiple calls depending on the size of the drive, and at the end of it you can use it to efficiently discover new or updated files and folders that are added in the future.

Comment: I would like to know whether we would be getting the deleted files json in the delta API

Comment: You may see deleted items come back, depending on whether the system believes your app had "seen" it before it was deleted. In this case you'd see a `deleted` facet to indicate that it's deleted.